# VBA to ask user if he wants to save the workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

I want users to get the option to save their workbook (if they have made any changes) at the beginning of my macro. How can I achieve this?

I've tried:

```
ThisWorkbook.Save
```

but unfortunately it doesn't generate any prompt.

I've also tried:

```
ThisWorkbook.Save(ThisWorkbook.FullName)
```

but it asks users if they are sure that they want to overwrite the existing file - so it gives a different prompt than the one I want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just wrap it with your own prompt:

```
If Not ThisWorkbook.Saved Then 
    If MsgBox("Do you want to save the file before continuing?",vbYesNo,"Save?") = vbYes Then
        ThisWorkbook.Save
    End If
End If
```

Comment: +1 You beat me by 9secs, I have deleted my post, they were to similar.

Comment: Cheers! I did see yours a few seconds after I posted -- nearly identical!